# Gated access to NFT hodlers

Tags: solidity

A company launched an NFT collection that has around 10k individual NFTs. Users trade these NFTs on an everyday basis, hence, Ownership of these NFTs is dynamic.

The same company now wants to release the IP/Content/Community related to the NFT collection and wants only the Holders of the NFT or allowed users can only access this content. The whole thing is on EVM smart contracts.

The problem: ONe-time access to many addresses can be done with Merkle tree. However, listening to new Transfer events and updating the Merkle tree will be costly.
Providing access with signatures from the company is also not feasible since they have to sign every new access by themselves.

Is there any other better way? PLease suggest.

Answer (score 0):

"company now wants to release the IP/Content/Community" - where will this content be released? If on a website, then the website just needs to check that the connected wallet holds the NFT via querying the NFT contract.

If on other venues, such as Discord, similar solutions can be obtained.